# Visual Studio vs. SQL Server Management Studio - Your Pick

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, version-control, ssms, database-management

Just to preface: I work in a small company that does ASP.NET development and uses SQL Server 2005 for all of our database needs.

I was curious as to what were the pros and cons of using Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio for our development on the database side (i.e. table creation, stored procedure writing, etc.).

Right now we perform all of our database tasks inside Management Studio and I was wondering if there was some benefit to using Visual Studio instead. Would it make it easier to keep track of procedure changes and other modifications to the database (whether that is through Visual Studio itself or through some type of source control (planning on implementing subversion soon).

I don't personally have problems working with Management Studio but if it would be more efficient and more controllable through Visual Studio in ways that I am just not familiar with I would love to hear about it.

**EDIT**: I just wanted to note that my specific development environments are SQL Sever 2005, Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition, and Visual Studio Team System 2008 Development Edition. We do not have team foundation server or any other extras running or installed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My personal method is to use SQL MS for all the design-related stuff (schema design, diagrams, keys, indexes, etc.), but to craft all my stored procedures, functions and the like in Visual Studio in a "Database" project attached to my solution -- mainly because it lets me keep the procs better version-controlled that way (as I find they generally change more often than the schema), and I find it's particularly handy using the context menus in VS to run the procs on my test and staging machines directly, since I do that so often.

Comment: The idea of using a database project to keep track of my stored procedures is definitely something that I was looking towards visual studio to be more convenient.

Answer (score 9):

IMHO one big advantage to using the management studio is "script as".  To my knowledge there is no equivalent in VS.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2010 has made some pretty nice upgrades to the SQL Server projects and solutions.  Read more here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160407003056/http://leonardwoody.com/2011/08/27/introduction-to-visual-studio-database-management/

Answer (score 3):

I used Management Studio for all of the SQL work earlier, but of late I've found that the in-house SQL manager of Visual Studio is pretty good too. I am using it more and more for running quick query checks, and modifications to the database scheme.

It's got a great feature of SQL indenting, and I've found it pretty helpful. In my view it beats SQL coloring of Management studio.

Answer (score 2):

That's a difficult question. I guess it would depend on exactly what you're doing. If you're building DALs and stuff, it would probably be easier to use VS, since there's some nice integration (drag-and-drop, etc.). VS is probably adequate for 95% of your daily db activity.

But as someone already mentioned, you don't get the "Script As" helpers (which I use all of the time). You also won't get much (if anything) in the way of user management tools (logons, etc.). And as far as I know, there is no way to manage indexes via Visual Studio. You don't get anything with regard to importing/exporting data either.

Comment: As of 2018 (I just browsed the documentation, and it does not have any publish date), Visual Studio supports indexes creation (see : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-editing-tables-indexes.html)

Answer (score 1):

For me Data Dude (aka Database Edition of Visual Studio 2008 Team System) has been a big game changer in terms of doing the very things your question addresses: keeping "track of procedure changes and other modifications to the database."  Not only can your team as a whole keep track of changes between various shared-environments, but through source control each team member can track his or her own differences relative to all of the shared environments. This makes database code truly code, with all of the attendant benefits.

Further, it's a snap to reconcile differences between databases and have the tool automatically generate the code that would reconcile those differences. Ideally database code would be released right out of source control, just as ASP.NET code would typically be done.  Data Dude greatly lessens the effort to achieve this parity.

The one negative is the cost: Data Dude requires an upgrade to Team System for those on Visual Studio Pro. Fortunately, evidently Microsoft is going to roll this functionality into the "Developer" edition of Visual Studio 2010, which presumably will have similar pricing to Visual Studio 2008 Pro.